# start angular function without click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in angular:

```
$scope.getSessionsForSpeaker = function (id) {
    $scope.id = id;
    $scope.getAll = SessionService.getAll();
    $scope.sessionsFound = [];
    $scope.getAll.$promise.then(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if ([data[i].speakers[0]] == $scope.id) {
                console.log([data[i].subject]);
                $scope.sessionsFound += [[data[i].subject] + ", "];
            }
        }
    });
};
```

and from html i run it by clicking a link:

```
<a ng-click="getSessionsForSpeaker(speaker.id)"></a>
```

Is there a way to run this function without clicking? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Just call it - after declaration add `$scope.getSessionsForSpeaker()`

Comment: What should be `speaker.id` in that case ?

Comment: You can do plenty. Do you want to call it on some event or from your code? You want it to run on when controller/link function runs etc.?

Comment: @Alexander is right. And you need to pass an `id `.

Comment: Chris, I want it to run when my page loads, or when I access a certain controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me:

```
<p ng-bind-html="sessionsFound"></p>
```

Thanks to everyone for contribution!

Answer (score 1):

You can run it from your controller if you know the ID:

```
$scope.getSessionsForSpeaker(id);
```

You can use `ng-init` to run it when that element loads:

```
<a ng-init="getSessionsForSpeaker(speaker.id)"></a>
```

You can also use `ng-mouseover` if you want to run it when the mouse is over that element

```
<a ng-mouseover="getSessionsForSpeaker(speaker.id)"></a>
```

All depends when you want to run it.

Comment: What's the point in creating a $scope method if a given function will only run in constructor function and will not get exposed as view model property?

Comment: He can run it from anywhere he likes, I have no idea how he wants to run it, so I've presented him with every choice I could think of.

Comment: <a ng-init="getSessionsForSpeaker(speaker.id)"></a> doesn't seem to work.